# Better approach for choosing outcome variable for regression: splitted into many or summed into one?

Tags: regression, modeling

Question: How local therapy offer affects actually received therapy?

I have three possibilities for choosing an outcome variable for regression:

```
Yt - total therapy hours (summed Y1 + Y2)

Y1 - type 1 therapy hours

Y2 - type 2 therapy hours
```

And I have two predictors, that correlate with each other, however, they have no causal relationship (work as mediators).

```
X1 - type 1 therapy offer

X2 - type 2 therapy offer
```

**Thus, which of these solutions would be smart to go:**

1. Summed approach: Yt ~ X1 + X2 (can show diminished effects due to correlation? Thus, I can have a wrong conclusion saying that there was no relationship between the offer and received therapy?)
2. Splitted approach: Y1 ~ X1 and Y2 ~ X2 (would this be better option?)